# Only embed / load audio of youtube video

Tags: audio, video, youtube, bandwidth

just messing around and cant find any answers to this question anywhere.

Is there a way to embed / only play the audio of a youtube video?

The idea is to use less bandwidth from not having to load a video etc.

I have seen people simply change the height of the embed so that only the controls are visible , but thats not what i want.

Im guessing this is impossible since the audio and video are one file that gets loaded.

Just thought would put this out there incase it it was possible or maybe another way of embedding a video and using less bandwidth?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any way to embed only audio of the youtube video. But you can tweak the view of player with CSS. A very good explanation is given at http://rcdewebmasters.wordpress.com/2012/04/19/embed-audio-only-youtube-video/. But that need to be checked for violation of **YouTube TOS**.